# Master pages or Templates

Tags: html, web

I am currently creating a web site with pure HTML ( No frameworks Just with plain HTML ).
It has lot of pages having a common navigation.

Is there a way to have feature like master pages of ASP.Net or template kind of thing which some other framework offer.

I am little reluctant to use the frame-sets.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your webserver allows you to use SSI (Server Side Includes) you can include common HTML files into your various pages to allow you to re-use some of your navigation and layout pages.

Ex.

```
<!--#include file="header.html"-->
<b>The main content here</b>
This content is in the main body
<!--#include file="footer.html"-->
```

Depending on the server configuration, you may need to change the extension of your file to .shtm or .shtml in order for the SSI commands to be processed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache you could use SSI Server Side Includes http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/ssi.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Dreamweavers Template mechanism. I've used it heavily for static websites, and it works. Copy/pasting the navigation into multiple pages isnt a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

For such websites, I use [Sleepy](http://code.google.com/p/sleepy-django/) with Python & Django.

> Sleepy, allows you to create a static
>   site by rendering Django templates to
>   HTML.

So basically, I can still use templates in my projects and Sleepy spits out the HTML.

You'll have to learn Django though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the only way to do this in HTML is to manually copy/paste the common code onto each page. If you were using any kind of framework or server side code then you could have that handle it, but with straight client-side HTML it's not doable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript/ajax to include files.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this ? 
My take on what are you saying is : 
Have a central content holder say div or something.
Then the JavaScript will fetch the central file depending on the navigation click. 

Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use template mechanisms that editors provide, as in Dreamweaver or even TextMate. Alternatively, you could use a generator like [jekyll](http://www.oiledmachine.com/posts/2008/12/27/overview-of-jekyll--a-static-site-generator-written-in-ruby.html) (its Ruby-powered, but I'm sure there are others).